# iOS - How to restrict application installs on different devices for a specific user

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am working on an in-house enterprise application. the idea is to restrict a specific user to install/run the application on X number of devices.

What is the best possible way to do that? The only way I can think of is using some kind of certificates ( the ones that you testflight or hockeyapp installs to uniquely identify the device and communicate back to server ). But I have no idea how to do that?

So how can I achieve this?

## EDIT

To Explain my question further, following is a sample scenario: '

"I have a video streaming application, and I want to restrict user to only use his login upto 5 different devices. when he will try to login on to the 6th device. the login will fail."

I want to achieve this functionality. I cannot generate random GUID and save it along the user details on server. as what if the user un-install the application on the same device and then installs again. there is no change that device will have the same GUID and will be considers by the server as a new device. I hope now my scenario is clear.

Comment: Commonly there is login view controller in In-House applications. Do you have such?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the default Ad-Hoc distribution. You get the UDID's from the devices, add them to your Apple developer portal, and then generate the new provisioning file once you've gotten all the devices you want. Testflight isn't needed, you can do this all on your own quite easily.

Comment: 1- this is limited to 100 devices. 2- you would have to manually update it for every single user, which is a pain when you have more than just a few users. This is mainly meant for testing with relatively small groups of users.

Comment: 100 is fine, as he stated X number of devices.

Comment: True, but XXX would indicate triple digit devices, so I assume single digit

Comment: Ad-Hoc is not a live distribution. I want the solution on Enterprise Live Applications. consider this scenario "I have a video streaming application, and I want to restrict user to only use his login upto 5 different devices. when he will try to login on to the 6th device. the login will fail." the Ad-Hoc distribution is all manual and I cannot take customers udids. I want the solution in LIVE. not TESTING

Comment: I have made an edit to my question. please take a look again.

Comment: Consider having an integer variable in your server database that when it reaches 5, the user cannot login on another device. When the user logs out, or the app terminates, call the server to decrement the integer.

Comment: @troop231: you can only control the number of current sessions with this approach. NOT the number of installs. User can still be able to install it on X devices. I want to restrict the number of Install.

Comment: Can you not use App Store promo codes as a solution?